How to debug where "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite. ts(2589)" is occuring?
I am getting this all of a sudden in my Next.js app:

Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite. ts(2589)

I can use // @ts-nocheck at the beginning of every file, one by one, rebuilding each time I add one, to see when it fails. But my app has thousands of files and I'm not sure what file introduced this (last commit touched 100 files, so I guess I could check those).
The error is sporadic as well, sometimes it succeeds to build (Next.js), sometimes it fails.
How can I debug this?
Adding this to my tsconfig.json doesn't help either:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "traceResolution": true,
    "extendedDiagnostics": true
    // ...
  }
}

Is there any way to see what is causing this error? All it says is that above error message, no stack trace or anything.
I don't have any more code to share, as there's no obvious usage of recursion in TS in my direct code. Perhaps my usage of Zod is funky, or Kysely, I don't know.

Without a [mre] I'm stumped. Surely you're getting that error message somewhere in particular, right? That's where I'd begin looking.

No, I'm not getting it anywhere in particular. I am running next build, and it says Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite. exit 1. No stack trace. No idea where in my large codebase this is happening. Hence the desire to print a stack trace.

I would go back, find the most recent commit where next build works, by dichotomy if needed

So then is this a question about next? Every time I've seen that error message from TSC, it's accompanied by information about where the error is. If your build is swallowing that, you need to work on that... maybe tag with next and provide information about your build?
